# Python: regex iteration to match word in list element

Tags: python, regex, iteration

**Set-up**

Scraping housing ads in London, I obtain per ad the address in a one-element list, e.g.

```
address=['Brockham Drive, Brixton SW2']
```

I have a dictionary linking London boroughs to their districts, e.g.

```
boroughs={ 
'Barking_Dagenham':['Barking', ..., 'Rush Green'],
'Barnet':['Arkley', ..., 'Woodside Park'],
    ⋮
'Westminster':['Bayswater', ..., 'Westminster'],
}
```

---

**Problem**

I want to check if the district name is in the `address`. If the district is in the `address`, then I want to create the variable `district` and `borough` indicating the district and its corresponding borough.

---

**Code tries**

*(1)*

```
for bor in boroughs.keys(): # loop over boroughs
   for distr in boroughs[bor]: # loop over borough's districts
      if distr in address[0]: # assign if district in address
         district = distr
         borough = bor
         break
      else:
         district = 'unknown'
         borough = 'unknown'
```

(1) doesn't work. That is, everything gets marked `'unknown'`.

I'm not sure if I am doing the `break` correctly nor if the `if distr in address[0]:` is the correct way to check for a match when iterating.

*(2)*

```
for bor in boroughs.keys(): # loop over boroughs
   for distr in boroughs[bor]: # loop over borough's districts
      district = re.search(r'\b'distr'\b', address[0]):    
      borough = ?
      break
   else:
      district = 'unknown'
      borough = 'unknown'
```

With (2), I am not sure how to correctly iterate over the 'bor' when using '\b'. Not sure how to assign the corresponding borough when iteration yields correct district match. Also, not sure if I should use (2) in stead of (1).

Which method should I use, and how can I get at least one of them to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code try #1 is correct, but missing one key element. You are only breaking out of the inner for loop, but then your code continues to loop through the outer for loop. Add a variable to check if it is found to break out of the outer for loop.

```
found = False

for bor in boroughs.keys(): # loop over boroughs
  for distr in boroughs[bor]: # loop over borough's districts
    if distr in address[0]: # assign if district in address
      district = distr
      borough = bor
      found = True
      break
    else:
      district = 'unknown'
      borough = 'unknown'
  if found:
    break
```

Comment: Or, even simpler, put both loops inside a funcion an `return` if found.

Comment: setting `district` and `borough` at each iteration is not efficient, better use the `for` + `else` construction. But as mentioned above, putting this in a function an using `return` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! Does the trick :) Just for my understanding, the `if found:` implies 'if `found` changes value, then `break` to stop for loop'?